# Retain checkbox state during paging

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview which contains checkbox and paging is enabled. Now when I check any of the checkboxes and then change the page, at that time all checked checkboxes loose their states. I want to retain the states of checkboxes during paging. How can I achieve this?

//Here is the code of .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="Search candidates based on vacancy" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/HR Department/hrmasterpage.master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="searcAppForVac.aspx.cs"    Inherits="HR_Department_searcAppForVac" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="tdtitle">
            Search Candidates
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="RowHeight" width="20%">
                                Select Company
                            </td>
                            <td width="30%">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="companyList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="companyList_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="150px">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="-Select Company-" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td width="20%">
                                Select Department
                            </td>
                            <td width="30%">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="deptList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True"
                                    onclick="Validate();" OnSelectedIndexChanged="deptList_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    Width="150px">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">-Select Department-</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="RowHeight" width="20%">
                                Select Vacancy
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="3" width="*">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="vacanyList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                    Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                    onselectedindexchanged="vacanyList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">-Select Vacancy-</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" align="center">
                                &nbsp;
                                <asp:Label ID="notifyLbl" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red" 
                                    Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <asp:Label ID="titleLbl" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red" 
                                    Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                &nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                <asp:GridView ID="appForVacGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                CellPadding="4" AllowPaging="True" 
                                    onpageindexchanging="appForVacGrid_PageIndexChanging" GridLines="None" 
                                    PageSize="3" CssClass="mGrid">
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                App.ID
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="appIdLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AppId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                First Name
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="firstNameLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AppFirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                Last Name
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lastNameLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AppLastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                Qualification
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="qualiNameLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QualiName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                &nbsp;Experience
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalExpYear") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                EmailId
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="emailLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AppEmailId1") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                Send Mail
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="sendMailBox" runat="server" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                                        HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                    <PagerStyle ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                        VerticalAlign="Top" CssClass="pgr" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                                        Font-Size="Medium" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" align="center">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="4">
                                <asp:Button ID="sendMailBtn" runat="server" Height="40px" Text="SEND MAIL" 
                                    Width="100px" onclick="sendMailBtn_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <%--<td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>--%>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="companyList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="deptList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="appForVacGrid" EventName="pageindexchanged" />
                </Triggers>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>


        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function alertOnBadSelection() {
        var select = document.getElementById('companyList');
        if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].value == "-Select Company-") {
            alert('Please Select Company!');
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

//Code of .aspx.cs page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;

public partial class HR_Department_searcAppForVac : System.Web.UI.Page
{
DataOperation oDo = new DataOperation();
AppVacancyDetailClass objAppVacDetail = new AppVacancyDetailClass();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyLbl.Visible = false;
    titleLbl.Visible = false;
    sendMailBtn.Visible = false;
    //mailSentLbl.Visible = false;
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Disable department dropdown list and vacancy dropdown list till company is not selected.
            deptList.Enabled = false;
            vacanyList.Enabled = false;
            //Fill Company dropdown list.
            DataTable objCmpnyTable = oDo.DropDownList("select * from tblCompanyMaster");
            if (objCmpnyTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                companyList.DataSource = objCmpnyTable;
                companyList.DataValueField = "CompId";
                companyList.DataTextField = "CompName";
                companyList.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                notifyLbl.Visible = true;
                notifyLbl.Text = "There is not any company in the list.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (companyList.SelectedIndex <= 0)
            {
                //Disable department dropdown list and vacancy dropdown list till company is not selected.
                deptList.Enabled = false;
                vacanyList.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          throw;
     }
 }
protected void companyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Disable vacancy dropdown list till depratment list is not selected
    vacanyList.Enabled = false;
    appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
    appForVacGrid.DataBind();
    try
    {
        if (companyList.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            deptList.Enabled = true;
            deptList.Items.Clear();
            string str = "select * from vwCompWiseList where CompId=" + companyList.SelectedValue;
            DataTable objDeptTable = oDo.DropDownList("select DeptId,DeptName from vwCompWiseDept where CompId= "+companyList.SelectedValue);
            if (objDeptTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                deptList.DataSource = objDeptTable;
                deptList.DataTextField = "DeptName";
                deptList.DataValueField = "deptId";
                deptList.DataBind();
                deptList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Department--", "-1"));
            }
            else 
            {
                deptList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--No Departments--", "-1"));
                notifyLbl.Visible = true;
                notifyLbl.Text = "No Departments Available in " + companyList.SelectedItem.Text;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            notifyLbl.Visible = true;
            notifyLbl.Text = "Select Company....";
            appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
            appForVacGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }    
}
protected void deptList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (deptList.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            vacanyList.Enabled = true;
            vacanyList.Items.Clear();
            DataTable objVacancytbl = oDo.DropDownList("select VacId,VacTitle from tblVacancyMaster where DeptId =" + deptList.SelectedValue + " and CompId=" + companyList.SelectedValue);
            if (objVacancytbl.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                vacanyList.DataSource = objVacancytbl;
                vacanyList.DataValueField = "VacId";
                vacanyList.DataTextField = "VacTitle";
                vacanyList.DataBind();
                vacanyList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Vacancy--", "-1"));
                appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
                appForVacGrid.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                notifyLbl.Visible = true;
                notifyLbl.Text = "ALL VACANCIES ARE CLOSED IN "+" "+deptList.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper();
                vacanyList.Enabled = false;
                appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
                appForVacGrid.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            notifyLbl.Visible = true;
            notifyLbl.Text = "Select Department...";
            appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
            appForVacGrid.DataBind();
            vacanyList.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
protected void vacanyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable AppListTbl = objAppVacDetail.GetValue("CompId=" + companyList.SelectedValue + " and DeptId=" + deptList.SelectedValue + " and VacId=" + vacanyList.SelectedValue);
        if (AppListTbl.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            appForVacGrid.DataSource = AppListTbl;
            appForVacGrid.DataBind();
            appForVacGrid.Columns[5].Visible = false;
            Session.Add("snAppListTbl", AppListTbl);
            titleLbl.Visible = true;
            titleLbl.Text = AppListTbl.Rows.Count.ToString() + " " + "CANDIDATE(S) ARE ELIGIBLE FOR THE POST OF" + " " + vacanyList.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper() + ".";
            sendMailBtn.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            notifyLbl.Visible = true;
            notifyLbl.Text = "ALL VACANCIES ARE CLOSED IN " + " " + deptList.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper();
            appForVacGrid.DataSource = null;
            appForVacGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
protected void appForVacGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
        //DataTable AppListTbl = (DataTable)Session["snAppListTbl"];
        titleLbl.Visible = true;
        titleLbl.Text = ((DataTable)Session["snAppListTbl"]).Rows.Count.ToString() + " " + "CANDIDATE(S) ARE ELIGIBLE FOR THE POST OF" + " " + vacanyList.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper() + ".";
        appForVacGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        appForVacGrid.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["snAppListTbl"];
        appForVacGrid.DataBind();
        sendMailBtn.Visible = true;
}
protected void sendMailBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable AppListTable = ((DataTable)Session["snAppListTbl"]);
    int intTotalRows = AppListTable.Rows.Count;
    string strFromId="chetan.patel@sahmed.com",strToId="",strCcId="",strBccId="";
    string strVacTitle="",strCompName="",strMailBody="";
    string strSubject = "Rgarding Selection of Your Resume";
    Label EmailLbl;
    bool isMailSent=false;
    //for (int intRow = 0; intRow < intTotalRows; intRow++)
    foreach (GridViewRow Row in appForVacGrid.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox objSendMail = (CheckBox)Row.FindControl("sendMailBox");
        //CheckBox objSendMail = (CheckBox)appForVacGrid.Rows[Row].FindControl("sendMailBox");
        if (objSendMail.Checked)
        {
            if (strToId == "")
            {
                //strToId = AppListTable.Rows[Row]["AppEmailId1"].ToString();
                EmailLbl = (Label)Row.FindControl("emailLbl");
                strToId = EmailLbl.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                //strToId += "," + AppListTable.Rows[Row]["AppEmailId1"].ToString();
                EmailLbl = (Label)Row.FindControl("emailLbl");
                strToId +=","+ EmailLbl.Text;
            }
        }
    }
    strVacTitle = vacanyList.SelectedItem.Text;
    strCompName = companyList.SelectedItem.Text;
    ////appForVacGrid.AllowPaging = false;
    ////appForVacGrid.DataBind();
     strMailBody = CommonProcedures.GetMailBody(strVacTitle, strCompName);
    isMailSent=CommonProcedures.SendMail(strFromId, strToId, strCcId, strBccId, strSubject, null, strMailBody, false);
    //appForVacGrid.AllowPaging = true;
    //appForVacGrid.DataBind();
     if (!isMailSent)
     {
         titleLbl.Visible = true;
         titleLbl.Text = "MAIL HAS BEEN SENT TO THE SELECTED APPLICANTS";
         sendMailBtn.Visible = true;
     }
     else
     {
         titleLbl.Visible = true;
         titleLbl.Text = "MAIL SENDING FAIL.... TRY AGAIN LATER..";
         sendMailBtn.Visible = true;
     }
     appForVacGrid.DataSource = AppListTable;
     appForVacGrid.DataBind();
}
```

}

Comment: Nice Question Number ... 5 million and 800 thousand :) --> stackoverflow.com/questions/5800000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Binding the Grid on page PageIndexChanging event so it doesn't possible with your code first you have to update the value of checkboxes to Datatable which is in session. so next time it will be show the checkBoxes selected..

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help you.
http://programming.top54u.com/post/Maintaining-Checkbox-state-while-GridView-Paging-in-C-sharp-ASP-Net.aspx